# Failed to install OlaMundo.apk on device 'emulator-5554': EOF

Tags: android, eclipse, avd

De vez em quando ao tentar rodar minha aplicação no emulador eu me deparo com o erro:

> [2014-07-23 20:59:09 - OlaMundo] Failed to install OlaMundo.apk on device 'emulator-5554': EOF
>   [2014-07-23 20:59:09 - OlaMundo] java.io.IOException: EOF
>   [2014-07-23 20:59:09 - OlaMundo] Launch canceled!

Depois disso quando eu tento rodar o aplicativo novamente o Eclipse abre um emulador novo ao invés de usar o emulador que já está aberto. Se eu impor ao Eclipse para me perguntar em qual dispositivo deve rodar, ele abre aquela janela para escolher, entretanto não aparece nenhum dispositivo já rodando (*Choose a running Android device*). É como se o emulador que está aberto não servisse mais, mas é muito demorado ficar abrindo um emulador novo a todo instante e eu gostaria de resolver isso.

Como evitar isso aconteça? Se não for possível impedir de acontecer, então como recuperar o emulador antigo de modo que eu não tenho que abrir um novo?

Aumentar o "*ADB connection timeout*" não fez a menor diferença.

Estou usando o Eclipse ADT Bundle versão "adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702", baixado do site [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

Comment: Possivelmente eh um erro da versão do emulador que pode estar travando o adb Server do emulador, por isso a conexão entre o adb do eclipse e do emulador cai, e não volta a detectar,  o que eu faria neste caso seria reinstalado pelo sdk manager esta API novamente.

Comment: @melkysalem apagar o ADT e criar um novo?

Comment: @Math, dê uma olhada no Genymotion. Tirando Android Wear, que ainda não tem no Genymotion (tem que ser usando AVD) eu nem uso mais AVD. Ele cria uma camada de abstração sobre a Virtual Box, gerenciando as imagens do Android e as configurações de vários dispositivos, não tem quase nenhum esforço de configuração (sua) é tudo automárico. E o melhor: It's Free! Há... tem plugin pra Eclipse e Android Studio.

Comment: @Wakim valeu pela dica!

Comment: @Wakim, apesar de não ter muita relação com a pergunta(eu acho), não conhecia o Genymotion. Instalei ele aqui e apenas de ter o dispositivo físico para testes, ele é muito bom, ou muito melhor que o AVD. Tinha brincado um pouco com  desenvolvimento Windows Phone (Visual Studio) e com IOS (xCode), e esse emulator não fica atras dos simuladores das outras respectivas IDEs. Boa dica. Meus 5 primeiros minutos testando o Genymotion é nota 10. e recomendo a todos que tenham problemas com o AVD, como no caso do Math.

Comment: @Fernando obrigado pelo feedback, pois ainda não testei e agora estou mais confiante ainda que vou testar e aprovar o Genymotion. Diga-se de passagem esse problema que tive com o AVD é apenas um deles, o AVD em si é horrível, sempre que possível usei o próprio celular.

Comment: Você também pode aumentar o timeout do emulador.
Veja mais: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775603/android-error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-timeout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso deve acontecer pois o emulador (na maioria dos casos) é lento demais, e quando o adb termina de instalar e envia os comandos de iniciar o app instalado o emulador ainda não está pronto e portanto não consegue abrir o app. Mas provavelmente o app foi instalado, e você consegue abrí-lo clicando no seu ícone dentro do emulador.

Quanto à dica do Wakim, eu ia te dizer a mesma coisa, dê uma chance ao [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/), é bem mais rápido, tem algumas funções muito legais como por exemplo simular a porcentagem da bateria ou bateria carregando por exemplo, e é grátis.

Valeu!